# Can a bash function or script be written that starts off the next command

Tags: bash, stdin, tty

Is it possible to write a function in .bashrc or a script that when called from the command line will start off the next command.

So if I have for example function defined as such:

```sh
el() {
  c0='less +G /var/log/very/long/base/'
  
  # something happens here
}
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
$ el
$ less +G /var/log/very/long/base/_
```

That is to say I don't want to type the long part, I only want to type el, and then have the rest inserted into the next command which I can finish off for example thus:

```
$ less +G /var/log/very/long/base/path.log
```

I know I can echo to stdout on a separate tty, so maybe it's possible to pipe stdin with a slight delay. Or maybe there is something built into bash. Has anyone done anything similar?

Comment: No, functions operate as separate commands. You should investigate customizing key bindings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `alias` instead of a function, or even an environment variable, let's call it EL.
With the latter, you can write something like

```
# $EL  <-- press tab here to show EL's value and complete
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
el() { less +G /var/log/very/long/base/; }
```

You can also set an alias but this will be gone as you exit the terminal session.

```
alias el="less +G /var/log/very/long/base/"
```

To make the alias permanent add the line to .bash_aliases

```
echo 'alias el="less +G /var/log/very/long/base/"' >> .bash_aliases
```

You can also add the function in your .bashrc file which will create the function everytime you start a terminal session.